# Use cmus or other terminal music player with Google Play (Music)

Tags: linux, terminal, music

Can you play/stream music through the linux terminal using a command line application from your Google Music/Play Account? If so how, and with what application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's theoretically possible using the [unofficial api](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API), but I am not aware of any existing clients.

Comment: Hmm, could probably do it myself then. Thanks, I'll get started.

Comment: @Link Make any progress on this? If so message me at the email in my profile.

Comment: @EricFossum, not at all... :C I just went with the web...

Comment: Hmm I'll give it a shot tonight or tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Try [thunner](https://github.com/iceiv/thunner), a python client. Here's a quick screenshot of the program:

[image: Thunner Screenshot]

Comment: Doesn't work. Google probably changed the API as it's not "officially" supported.